# Neo4j - relationships not working after including type in ROR classes definition

Tags: neo4j

I am getting and author but all work of arts belonging to the author are no longer retrieved.

```
> a = Author.find_by(author_name: 'Camus, Albert')
=> #<Author author_id: 615454, author_name: "Camus, Albert">

> w = a.wokas
=> <AssociationProxy @query_proxy=<QueryProxy Author#wokas#wokas CYPHER: "MATCH author615452, author615452-[rel1:`authored`]->(result_wokas:`Woka`) WHERE (ID(author615452) = {ID_author615452})">>

> w.count
=> 0
```

I should get like 300+ records.

In the DB the name of relationship is AUTHORED and the classes definition are:

```
class Author
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :author_name,  type: String
  property :author_id,    type: Integer
  has_many :out, :wokas, type: 'authored'
end

class Woka
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :author_id,    type: Integer
  property :publisher_id, type: Integer
  property :language_id,  type: Integer
  property :woka_id,      type: String #Integer
  property :woka_title,   type: String
  has_one :in, :author,     type: 'authored'
  has_one :in, :publisher,  type: 'published'
  has_one :in, :language,   type: 'used'
  has_many :out, :bisacs,       type: 'included'
  has_many :out, :descriptions, type: 'has_language'
end
```

Any clue why the relationships are not longer working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associations return `AssociationProxy` objects now.  In the past they returned `QueryProxy` objects.  Both are there to allow you to make chained calls on further associations or other class-level methods.  Like this:

```
# Returns another `AssociationProxy` which you can use to get all of the description objects
a.wokas.descriptions
```

If you want to see the objects from the association you can call `to_a` on the result like this:

```
w = a.wokas.to_a
```

Or you could simply iterate since `AssociationProxy` objects are `Enumerable`:

```
a.wokas.each do |woka|
  # Do something with the woka object
end
```

As a side note, one of the reasons the `AssociationProxy` is there is to allow for eager loading as [described here](http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ActiveNode.html#eager-loading) (again, that documentation won't be complete until the final release of 5.0).

Lastly for performance reasons I'd suggest using symbols whenever you can.  For your associations, for example, you can do this:

```
has_many :out, :wokas, type: :authored
```

Comment: The retuned array is empty.


irb(main):018:0* w = a.wokas.to_a
=> []

Comment: Change all classes definition from type: 'something' to type: :something.


Same error, no changes, empty result set for "child records".

Comment: I don't expect changing thing to symbols to change the result of the query, just to run a bit faster.  One thing I forgot to mention: If you run `a.wokas.to_cypher` it will show you the Cypher command that it's trying to execute which can help you debug

Comment: > a.wokas.to_cypher
=> "MATCH author615452, author615452-[rel1:`authored`]->(result_wokas:`Woka`) WHERE (ID(author615452) = {ID_author615452})"

Comment: Trying to execute this in the neo4j console and I am getting errors.

$ MATCH author615452, author615452-[rel1:`authored`]->(result_wokas:`Woka`) WHERE (ID(author615452) = {ID_author615452});
QueryExecutionKernelException: Query cannot conclude with MATCH (must be RETURN or an update clause) (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0))
"MATCH author615452, author615452-[rel1:`authored`]->(result_wokas:`Woka`) WHERE (ID(author615452) = {ID_author615452})"
 ^

Comment: You need to have a `RETURN` in your query when you put it in the console.  I expect it's because it's querying for `authored` and not `AUTHORED`.  I think I was mistaken before about `transform_rel_type` uppercasing for you.  Apparently that only happens when the type is being created for you, so I would uppercase it in your model

Comment: I changed to capital letters all the symbols for relationships and now everything works well. I have one single question: how the RETURN clause should look for this query? I don't know how to write it in case I want to test it from the database console.


MATCH author615452, author615452-[rel1:`AUTHORED`]->(result_wokas:`Woka`) WHERE (ID(author615452) = {ID_author615452})

Comment: When `ActiveNode` iterates over the association it simply addes a `RETURN result_wokas` onto the end

Comment: Didn't worked, here is the error resulted.

$ MATCH author615452, author615452-[rel1:`AUTHORED`]->(result_wokas:`Woka`) WHERE (ID(author615452) = {ID_author615452}) RETURN result_wokas;
QueryExecutionKernelException: Expected a parameter named ID_author615452

Comment: Oh, right ;)  The other thing that you need to do is replace the parameter (`{ID_author615452}`) with the ID.  I'm pretty sure that's going to be 615452

Comment: Still errors: $ MATCH author615452, author615452-[rel1:`AUTHORED`]->(result_wokas:`Woka`) WHERE (ID(author615452) = ID) RETURN result_wokas;               
QueryExecutionKernelException: ID not defined (line 1, column 101 (offset: 100))

Comment: Don't replace it with the characters `ID`, replace it with the ID of the node (again, I think that would be 615452)

Comment: That worked, many thanks, here is the successful one as you suggested: MATCH author615452, author615452-[rel1:`AUTHORED`]->(result_wokas:`Woka`) WHERE (ID(author615452) = 615452) RETURN result_wokas;